# Getting all the solutions to a predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm writing a text adventure game in Prolog, and I am printing out room exits. I have code that does:

```
exits_from(Room) :-
  connected(Room, X),
  write(X), write('  ').
```

where connected/2 is:

```
connected(X, Y) :- path(X, Y).
connected(X, Y) :- path(Y, X).
```

and path is:

```
path(room, hallway).
path(hallway, foyer).
```

and so on.

When I am printing the exits for a room though, it gets the first, then wants a ';' to say that I want another solution. Is there anyway to force a predicate to compute the result entirely, so that the player wouldn't have to keep asking for more exits?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

one way is to do something like

```
print_all_solutions :-
  solution(Sol),
  write(Sol),
  fail. % this causes backtracking
print_all_solutions. % succed
```

another is to use special predicate forall, like follows:

```
forall(solution(Sol), write(Sol))
```

Comment: Is forall built in for some implementations? It's not valid in gprolog apparently. But thanks for the backtracking tip!

Comment: According to this http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#htoc103 gprolog has findall/3.

Comment: findall/3 is not the same as forall/2.

Comment: for first solution ,print true at the last of result `print_all_solutions
1 2 3 True
1 Solution`