# how can I print all database facts in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a database in prolog, all I want to do is enuamrate through its element and print one by one. How can this be done?

```
fact(is(mike,asthmatic)).
fact(has(andy,highPressure)).
fact(is(mike,smoker)).
```

I have written this, which works ok but it removes elements from the database, so I want to access them without removing.

```
print:- 
  retract(factA(P)),
    write(factA(P)),nl,
    fail.
  print.
```

Comment: If you don't want to remove, then just don't call `retract/1`...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting all the solutions to a predicate in Prolog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846145/getting-all-the-solutions-to-a-predicate-in-prolog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might also consider using `forall/2` predicate:

```
print:-
 forall(fact(P), writeln(P)).
```

Comment: it worked when I changed this code to: print:-
 forall(fact(P), (write(P), nl)). Can you tell me why writeln didn't work? Is it compiler dependent?

Comment: well it depends if the predicate `writeln/1` is available for your implementation. Seems it's not ! Which prolog are you using ?

Comment: Apparently GNU Prolog doesn't have `writeln(Term)` which, as you have said, is equivalent to `(write(Term), nl)`. Therefore you could also wrote your own version of writeln/1: `writeln(Term):- write(Term), nl.`

Answer (score 4):

Well, you were almost there :

```
print :-
    fact(A),
    writeln(A),
```

First, we get a fact and print it.

```
    fail;true.
```

Then, we backtrack (through fail) until no solution is left. To avoid returning false, we add the disjunction with true.

Note that you can proceed differently, like :

```
print2 :-
    findall(Fact, fact(Fact), Facts),
    maplist(writeln, Facts).
```

But if you go that road, prefer @gusbro solution, it's better !