# How to print all facts?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to print all facts in my Prolog problem. Have searched the forum for a while and can't seem to find a solution to the problem. I tried the [how can I print all database facts in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510701/how-can-i-print-all-database-facts-in-prolog) but can't seem to make it work. Im doing a menu for it, so, when I press the corresponding key, it should show me all the facts and print back the menu. Something like this (its not complete):

```
 if_then_else(P,Q,R):- P,!,Q.
 if_then_else(P,Q,R):- R.

 :- dynamic client/2.
client(john,password).
client(charles,bird).

printmenu:- write('1-Print all facts').
        read(X),
        if_then_else(X=1,printfacts,(error,printmenu)).

printfacts:-
```

Comment: Why defining an `if_then_else/3` predicate when there's a built-in if-then-else control construct?

Comment: What does `error` do (Besides give an error, `error/0 undefined procedure`)?

Answer (score 3):

Why not

```
printfacts :-
    forall(client(X, Y),format('client(~w, ~w)~n', [X, Y])).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to print the facts (not return them all in a list or whatever), then:

```
printfacts :-
    client(X, Y),
    format('client(~w, ~w)~n', [X, Y]),
    false.
printfacts.
```

Your `printmenu` could be written:

```
printmenu :-
    repeat,
    write('1-Print all facts').
    read(X),
    (   X = 1
    ->  printfacts
    ;   write('Invalid response'), nl,
    ),
    fail.             % Go back to the top and reprompt
```